# Android | java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@1219dd0f: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881396 at offset 660

Tags: android, parcelable, runtimeexception

Please help me how to solve this issue ?

Parcelable interface i was implemented in customer pojo object. please help me how to read customer object in activity 2 ?

**Customer.java**

```
public Customer implements Parcelable{
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private List<AccountDetails> accoutDetails;

/getter and setters

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public Customer(Parcel in) {
    name= in.readString();
    phone= in.readString();
    accoutDetails= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
    in.readList(accoutDetails,null);


}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Customer> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Customer>() {
    public Customer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Customer(in);
    }

    public Customer[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Customer[size];
    }
};

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(this. name);
    dest.writeString(this.phone);

    dest.writeList(accoutDetails);
}

}
```

In **activity 1** used below code:

```
Customer selected_row=(Customer) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("selected_customer", selected_row);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2:**

```
 Customer cust_object = getBundle.getParcelable("selected_customer");
```

Please find the **below exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@1219dd0f: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881396 at offset 660
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2228)
at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:1661)
```

Please help me how to read customer object in activity 2 ?

Comment: Post the full logcat error

Comment: Edit it into your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization, although supported, is not recommended for Android. See for example [this post](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development).

I think that your issue is on this line of code:

```
in.readList(accoutDetails,null);
```

Since accountDetails is a List of custom AccountDetails objects you need AccountDetails to also implement Parcelable.

Do that, and then change the above line of code to:

```
in.readTypedList(accoutDetails, AccountDetails.CREATOR);
```

**EDIT 1**

Also, change:

```
public Customer(Parcel in) {
    name= in.readString();
    phone= in.readString();
    accoutDetails= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
    in.readTypedList(accoutDetails,null);
}
```

to:

```
public Customer(Parcel in) {
    name= in.readString();
    phone= in.readString();
    in.readTypedList(accoutDetails, AccountDetails.CREATOR);
}
```

And change:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(this. name);
    dest.writeString(this.phone);

    dest.writeList(accoutDetails);
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.phone);
    dest.writeTypedList(accoutDetails);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public Customer implements Parcelable{
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private List<AccountDetails> accoutDetails = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
```

Comment: I tried with in.readTypedList(accoutDetails, AccountDetails.CREATOR). but parent data is coming. Account Details list is coming null

Comment: As accountDetails is the list of AccountDetails. reference

Comment: bundle.putParcelable("selected_customer", selected_row)-> in selected_row contains customer object+ list of account for that customer

Comment: Customer selected_row=(Customer) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

Comment: Its a customer : its one to many relationship: Once if click the customer we need to show account details of selected customer in activity 2

Comment: Yes now null exception is not coming but i am getting accountDetails is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88013/discussion-between-midaslefko-and-nag).